# how to Personalize my site using facebook

Tags: php, facebook

i want to integrate facebook login in my site and want to extract information from user. here is my code

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Facebook Login Page
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="fb-root">
      <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
      <script>
         FB.init({ 
            appId:'my app id', cookie:true, 
            status:true, xfbml:true 
         });
      </script>
     <h3>Welcome to my site</h3>
      <fb:login-button>Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Here is the link [click here](http://www.cpantry.com/match/) of my site everything is ok but my question what should do after this how can i use graph API to extract user information using php.
any help with example would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to start learning the concepts by reading the [Facebook Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/).
2. Try using the [Facebook PHP-SDK](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk) along with your approach, there's an [example](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) too!
3. From the example above: `$me = $facebook->api('/me');` will contain the user data
4. Depending on your needs, you may need to request additional [permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) from the user. This can be done like this: `<fb:login-button perms="user_birthday"></fb:login-button>`
5. Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Comment: +1 for your precise answer. ifaour I would like to know in almost your all question your insists the persons to use php sdk. Can you please tell me what is the reason? what are the basic benifits of using that instead of simple integration?

Comment: @Awais Qarni: first of all thnx. As you noticed most of the questions are asked from a new comers and most of the time SDKs help simplifying *advanced* calls and functionalities like the [authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) process and `access_token` exchange for example.